# Get Error information while in Production, Django

Tags: django, error-handling, production, http-status-code-500

I'm getting this weird error which only shows when the app i am working on is in production. While its easy to identify and fix the error in development, I'm getting a 500 error page when I switch to production.

I'm trying to get a way to discover the error details in productions but this is proving difficult. Some assistance will help. Thanks.

Comment: The only way you will be able to debug this issue is to get access to the error log, this will contain a stacktrace that should lead you to the cause of your error

Comment: If you are only getting the error when `DEBUG = False` your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting might be incorrect. Otherwise I recommend always using an application monitoring tool such as sentry.io

Comment: How do i access the stacktrace or set up so that the stacktrace can be generated upon an error?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/ or as Selcuk already proposed you can use monitoring tools if you dislike digging the logs